# iPhone - properties of a list of files

Tags: iphone, uitableview, detailsview, nsfilemanager

I have an mutableArray which displays a list of files in a tableView. I have stored those files in a directory.

I am using `NSfileManager` class and `attributesOfItemAtPath` method to retrieve some properties of the files like fileSize, fileType..

In the second stage I am trying to have a detailView controller which displays the properties of the particular file when touched in the tableView.

The problem is I dont know how to bind those properties like fileSize and fileType separately to a `NSDictionary` and make it display in the detailView for that particular file.

Here is my source code for listing the files and to list the properties.

```
- (void)listFiles {

    NSFileManager *fm =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    NSArray *paths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        error = nil;
    }
    directoryContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *path in paths){
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        [directoryContent addObject:documentsDirectory];
    }
}

-(void) willProcessPath {
    NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:nil];
    for (NSString *path in paths){
        filesPath = [parentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        NSDictionary *attrDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:filesPath error:nil];
        filesSize = [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        filesName = (NSString *)directoryContent;
        filesType = [path pathExtension];
        createdDate = [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
        modifiedDate = [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
    }
}
```

Please help me to proceed to the next step.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    won't work on a real device

Comment: Ya. I am just trying in the simulator. I will change the directory when using in the device.

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted answers that solve your problems. Or at least provide some sort of feedback instead of just not answering anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self listFiles];
}



- (void)listFiles {

    NSFileManager *fm =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *parentDirectory = [self getDocumentsPath];
    NSArray *paths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        error = nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.directoryContent = array;
    [array release];

    for (NSString *path in paths){
        NSString *fullPath = [self getPathToFileInDocumentsDirectory:path];
        NSMutableDictionary *filePropertiesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil]];
        [filePropertiesDictionary setObject:fullPath forKey:@"fullPath"];
        [filePropertiesDictionary setObject:path forKey:@"fileName"];
        [directoryContent addObject:filePropertiesDictionary];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", directoryContent);
}

- (NSString *)getDocumentsPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return documentsDirectoryPath;  
}
- (NSString *)getPathToFileInDocumentsDirectory:(NSString *)fileName {
    return [[self getDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}
```

Comment: Um. I tried that in Xcode and it does work. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Nothing comes in the tableView and in the console.

Comment: Do you have any documents in the Documents folder? If not, you will not get any output. There is no output in the view anyway, just in the console. Make sure to put some docs in that folder... if you want to know the path to the folder on your machine, just put in an NSLog somewhere -> NSLog(@"%@", parentDirectory);

Comment: Now I added some files to the path. But It shows an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2cf40'

Comment: Well, then you probably have an error in your code somewhere. Post your complete xcode project somewhere, and I will have a look.

Comment: Please send me your mail id. I will send you through mail.

Comment: Oh! I just used the code which was given above by you. No change in it. The path also have the files.

Comment: @interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
 NSMutableArray *directoryContent;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *directoryContent;

- (void)listFiles;
- (NSString *)getDocumentsPath;
- (NSString *)getPathToFileInDocumentsDirectory:(NSString *)fileName;

@end

Comment: Ya.. everything is right. But the tableView terminates showing the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much yar. I tried a little with your help. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class "FileDescriptor" with the following properties:

```
NSString *fileName;
NSString *fileSize;
NSString *fileType;
NSDate *createdDate;
NSDate *modifiedDate;
```

When iterating over your directory, you create an instance of this class for each file, and store that in an array (or a dictionary, if you like). Then you can use that array to

a) provide data for your UITableViewCells

b) show a detail view for each file when the cell is clicked.

Should you want to use a dictionary instead (which I think is a lot less "clean") you can do so like this:

```
NSDictionary *fileProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  fileSize, @"fileSize", 
  fileName, @"fileName", nil];
```

Comment: Thank u. But can u narrate in detail with a source code about how to use a NSDictionary in this?

Comment: Well, if you want to use a dictionary instead of a custom object (which I think will make the code only messier, you can store those values like this:
NSDictionary *fileProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fileSize, @"fileSize", fileName, @"fileName" ... etc...., nil];

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary instead of an array, you put the objects that describe your file into a dictionary, with e.g. the absolute file path as the key. When you retrieve them to show in your table, you could use FileDescriptor *aFileDescriptor = [[yourDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I'd like to use dictionary instead of custom object, as you said. Can you please send me a reference for using this of method? Or any source code about how to initiate?

Comment: Hi I tried. But its not working. The console is showing (null) when I run it. Please, if possible, use your method in my code and post it.

Comment: Can you post your complete class somewhere? Maybe pastebin?

Comment: The two methods I used is in the next answer for this post.

Comment: The header is in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)listFiles {

    NSFileManager *fm =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    NSArray *paths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        error = nil;
    }
    directoryContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *path in paths){
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        [directoryContent addObject:documentsDirectory];
    }
}

-(void) willProcessPath {
    NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:nil];
    for (NSString *path in paths){
        filesPath = [parentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        NSDictionary *attrDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:filesPath error:nil];
         filesDirectory = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:filesSize, [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileSize],
                      filesName, (NSString *)directoryContent, filesType, [path pathExtension],
                      createdDate, [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate],
                      modifiedDate, [attrDir objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate], nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", filesDirectory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyFilesList : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *directoryContent;
    IBOutlet UITableView *filesTable;
    IBOutlet NSNumber *filesSize;
    IBOutlet NSString *filesName;
    IBOutlet NSString *filesType;
    IBOutlet NSString *filesPath;
    IBOutlet NSDate *createdDate;
    IBOutlet NSDate *modifiedDate;
    NSMutableDictionary *filesDirectory;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *directoryContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *filesTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSNumber *filesSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *filesName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *filesType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *filesPath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSDate *createdDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSDate *modifiedDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *filesDirectory;

- (void)listFiles;
- (void) willProcessPath;
@end
```

Comment: 1. I don't see you setting all those variables anywhere. 
2. If you use [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:], you need to specify an object after the colon, then a key, then an object, then a key etc. and then nil. Currently you are storing filesName (which is nil, as you did not assign it anyhwere) with the key (NSString *)directoryContent. That makes no sense.